# Azure function temp storage | NODE

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

In an Azure function, I am receiving a file from a POST request. While testing it saves the file In local disk and it uploads to google drive perfectly. While in production the script has no errors but the file never uploads. It is because I need to load the file into a temp file with no luck. I tried replacing FileName with `C:\local\Temp\${fileName}`.  - Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      const createWrite = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(fileName, buf, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
      createWrite.then(() => {
        const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
        var fileMetadata = {
          name: `${projectName} -  ${fileName}`,
          parents: [`${target}`]
        };
        const media = {
          mimeType: "[*/*]",
          body: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
        };
        drive.files.create(
          {
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            fields: "id"
          },
          (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
              // Handle error
              console.error(err);
            } else {
            //  Do something here

            }
          }
        );
      });
```

Comment: In Azure function, we do not have permissions to read and write file in driver C. We can write files into `D:/home` or %TMP%. For more details, pleas refer to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system

Answer (score 1):

As Jim mentioned in comments, we can't read/write file in driver C. We can just write files into `d:\\local\\Temp` (you can also use `%TMP%`, they are same).

And by the way, if you upload the file in `d:\\local\\Temp`, please do the upload in current running instance of your function. Because if you deploy the function in consumption plan, the files(under `d:\\local\\Temp`) are not shared among each instances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a linux host so form me the only thing that worked was this:

```html
const os = require('os');
const outputDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "output")
if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
   fs.mkdirSync(outputDir);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to use this to store my CSV file from a download but when I go to retrieve it I get a file not found error. What was the exact syntax you used to then read from that location?

Comment: ```const dstPath = path.join(outputDir, `filename`);
        fs.readFile(dstPath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          context.log.error(err)
        } else {
          context.log(data)
        }
      });```