# Azure Functions linux nodejs storing and retrieving files

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, azure-functions, node.js-fs

I have a nodejs instance running in an Azure Function App. Using Puppeteer I am able to navigate through a website and download file.

I created a path using node os and tmpdir() as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822697/azure-function-temp-storage-node/65932890) and this snippet:

```
const downloadPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), '/downloads/');
```

I confirm the path is as expected with a context.log:

```
context.log('Download path: ' + downloadPath);
```

which returns `Download path: /tmp/downloads/`

I create the directory with the next snippet:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(downloadPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(downloadPath, { recursive: true });
}
```

I then have a function that watches that folder and returns the filename when a file is added to that folder:

```
async function watchFolderForFile(ctx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const watcher = fs.watch(downloadPath, async (eventType, fileName) => {
      ctx.log('watching folder');
      if (eventType === 'rename') {
        // A file has been added
        watcher.close();
        resolve(fileName);
      }
    });

    // Handle errors
    watcher.on('error', async (err) => {
      watcher.close();
      reject(err);
    });
 });
}
```

This all works well and I can see the file now exists as the concatenated string of /tmp/downloads/DonationsReport-CharityId-2956110-from-2022-01-01-to-2022-01-31.Csv.crdownload

But when I call the file to read it I get an error that the file doesn't exist. Should I be doing anything different because it is in an Azure Function App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours and trial and error I was able to solve it. As the Azure Function App is running in a linux environment the folder structure is different and `os.tmpdir()` will not work. I was able to store and retrieve files by using the `/home/` directory.

Hope this helps someone in future!